# Multiple Sources in One Gulp Stream

Tags: javascript, gulp, concatenation

We have three sets of JavaScript files that need to run through different tools during the build process and then be concatenated into one `scripts.js` file.

1. vendorScripts - no processing here, simply concatenate these files with the rest
2. foundationScripts - files need to be processed through Babel
3. customScripts -  files need to be processed through Babel & checked with JShint

This is also the same order we need these files to output.

I've seen some ways that use temporary directories, but it feels so "dirty" to do that. Is there a way to achieve the above in a single Gulp task/function?

Below is what I setup using Gulp 4 passthroughs. It completes the correct processes on each set of files, however, there is no control over the order of the output (vendorScripts **need** to come first).

```
function buildScripts() { 
    return gulp.src(SOURCE.customScripts) // Only use jshint on Custom Scripts
        .pipe(plugin.jshint())
        .pipe(plugin.jshint.reporter('jshint-stylish'))

    .pipe(gulp.src(SOURCE.foundationScripts, {passthrough: true})) // Run Foundation Scripts and Custom Scripts through Babel
        .pipe(plugin.babel({
            presets: ['es2015'],
            compact: true
        }))

    .pipe(gulp.src(SOURCE.vendorScripts, {passthrough: true})) // Grab extra vendor files, concantonate all together

    .pipe(plugin.concat('scripts.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(ASSETS.scripts))    
}
```

Comment: You should look into merging separate steams for each subtask  ala https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/4.0/docs/recipes/using-multiple-sources-in-one-task.md